# Possible way to show date in format 'YYYY/MM/DD' using lightning-input-field / lightning-output-field?

Tags: lightning-web-components

In my custom LWC component, I out put a date-type field using lightning-output-field tag, and it is formatted by default 'YYYY-MM-DD',

is it possible to show 'YYYY/MM/DD' using lightning-output-field and lightning-input-field?

Or I have to use lightning-input tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lightning-output-field` and `lightning-input-field` respect running users' locale.

from [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-output-field/documentation)

> ...if field-name references a date and time value, then the default
> output value contains the date and time in the user's locale.

That means, that you can control it by changing the user's locale. So for users with different locals, this field will be displayed in different formats.

If you want to have some static format of date, you'll need to use  `lightning-input` and to set desired date format.

Comment: perfect, thank you.